Next.js: How to Prevent Cached Downloads of Updated Files?
I'm working on a Next.js app where users download a license file. After replacing the file on the server, users still download the old version. I suspect caching issues.
Here's the code generating the download link:
<a
  target="_blank"
  href={`${apibaseUrl}/files/upload/user_licence_file/${licenseFileFirst}`}
>
  <span className="text-success text-center">
    <CloudArrowDownIcon className="h-16 w-16 m-auto" />
  </span>
</a>

Here is the function for fetching data:
async function getData(productId, user_id) {
  const url = `${apibaseUrl}/api-user/user-activation-course-page`;
  const bodyData = { product_id: productId, user_id: user_id };

  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate",
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        "Expires": "0",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(bodyData),
      cache: "no-cache",
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
      console.log("Error in response: ", response.statusText);
      return null;
    }

    return response.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Failed to fetch data:", error);
    return null;
  }
}

How can I ensure users always download the most recent version of the file?
